# Constant in class << self block

Tags: ruby

In the following fragment, is it possible to refer to the FOO constant from outside the module, and if so, how?

```
module X
  class << self
    FOO = 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class <<X
  self
end::FOO
```

or

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class <<self
      self
    end
  end
end

X.metaclass::FOO
```

Comment: There's no built-in method to get the metaclass? I guess the conclusion is that putting constants within the `class <<self` block is usually misguided.

Comment: @MichieldeMare Yes.. Ruby has. Like `X.singleton_class::Foo`.