# Module class << self constants

Tags: ruby, module, constants, self

Is there my `L` constants?

```
module M
  class Z
    class << self
      L = "foo"
    end
  end
end

=> M::Z::L
=> NameError: uninitialized constant M::Z::L
=> M::Z.constants
=> []

module B
  class N
    X = "bar"
  end
end

=> B::N::X
=> "bar"
=> B::N.constants
=> [:X]
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281057/constant-in-class-self-block) but I do not understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constant in class << self block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281057/constant-in-class-self-block)

Comment: @toro2k yeah i see that, but this is a dirty hack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do as :

```
module M
  class Z
    class << self
      L = "foo"
    end
  end
end

M::Z.singleton_class::L # => "foo"
```

`L` is defined inside the singleton class of `Z`.

`"L"` is stored in the set of constants of the singleton class of `M::Z`, You may call it `S` for now. `M::Z::L` it actually is searching this constant `L`, in the constant table of `M::Z` and its ancestors. since none of them is `S`, the look-up fails.

Comment: I forgot about eigenclass))

Comment: This is a peeve of mine. It's called the [singleton class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class).